# Getting active elements of task manager

Tags: c++, winapi

Okay, I want to delete my app from Applications list in Windows task maneger. I found the following code code:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Hack_Windows_Task_Manager.aspx

I wanted to do it in C/C++ so I code this:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

BOOL CALLBACK Usun(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam);
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd;
    while (true)
    {
        hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,"Menedżer zadań Windows"); //<-- it's in polish and it is finding window without problems
        if (hwnd == NULL) std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
            EnumChildWindows(hwnd,Usun,NULL);
            Sleep(500);
        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK Usun(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
    char zakladka[256] = {0};
    GetWindowText(hwnd,zakladka,256);
    char lista[256] = {0};
    GetClassName(hwnd,lista,256);
    if ((strcmp(zakladka,"Aplikacje") == 0) && (strcmp(lista,"SysListView32") == 0))
    { //Aplikacje is the same as Tasks
        std::cout << "Found SysList" << std::endl;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

But the program is not working they way it should.

IMPORTANT: IT'S NOT MEANT TO BE SOME VIRUS PROGRAM

Comment: Please describe how it is working, and in what way that is not the way it should.

Comment: Code is suppose to print in console: Found SysList but it does not. I open task meneger go to Tasks tab and nothing is getting printed.

Comment: Did your app appears in task bar?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you want to restrict users from doing something, then do it via permissions, not information hiding.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should also hide your app from task bar. Check this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/hidetaskbar.aspx